# Why is it when posting an object into a json file, one of the key/value always appears as curly braces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

So, i have this form button, when pressed, it posts and object into an array called "notes".
This object is filled with form field values, and a return of a function (ex.: a function that returns the creation date).
I've created another function to return the idm which is basicaly the lenght of the array "notes".
The creation date return, appears fine in the json file, however the id function always appears as curly braces.

I suspect it may be the async await keyworks, because if i create simple functio to return "hello", in the json file appears as "hello".

If someone knows this, i would appreciate the help.

The object being posted:

```
let userNote = { // the object
        noteName: noteNameInput.value,
        important: noteImportant.value,
        reminder: noteDateInput.value,
        noteMsg: noteMsgInput.value,
        creationDate: creationDate(),
        id: id()
    }
let data = JSON.stringify(userNote);
```

The functions:

```
function creationDate(){
    let today = new Date();
    let day = today.getDate();
    let month = today.getMonth()+1;
    let year = today.getFullYear();
    let currentDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
    return currentDate;
}
function id(){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
            const req = await fetch(`http://localhost:${PORT}/api`);
            const data = await req.json();
            let id_number = (data.notes.length);
            const error = false;
            //------------
            if(!error){
                resolve(id_number);
            } else {
                reject('Something went wrong!');
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

The json file (*i started trying after "teste2"):

```
{"notes":[{"noteName":"teste1","important":"on","reminder":"2021-10-20","noteMsg":"teste1","creationDate":"7/10/2021"},{"noteName":"teste2","important":"on","reminder":"2021-10-28","noteMsg":"teste2","creationDate":"7/10/2021"},{"noteName":"teste3","important":"off","reminder":"2021-10-21","noteMsg":"teste3","creationDate":"7/10/2021","id":{}},{"noteName":"teste4","important":"off","reminder":"2021-10-19","noteMsg":"teste4","creationDate":"7/10/2021","id":{}},{"noteName":"teste5","important":"off","reminder":"2021-10-21","noteMsg":"teste5","creationDate":"7/10/2021","id":{}},{"noteName":"a","important":"off","reminder":"2021-10-21","noteMsg":"a","creationDate":"7/10/2021","id":{}}]}
```

*i've try with and without promises, to same end result. (the curly braces problem)

Comment: `id` returns a promise so you need to await that too.

Comment: ^ `id: await id()`

Comment: @Andy, broooooo, i feel stupid, thank you so much, i couldn't find the answer anywhere.