# Function is returning curly braces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

i've asked very similar question before ([Why is it when posting an object into a json file, one of the key/value always appears as curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481042/why-is-it-when-posting-an-object-into-a-json-file-one-of-the-key-value-always-a)), and hate asking it again but i can´t find the answer anywhere.
So i have this function that returns "hello" (it should return a certain value, but error happens either way, so i have "hello" for testing).

```
function index(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $("#noteDisplay").on("click", ".remove", (e) => {
                //indexResult = (e.currentTarget.parentNode.id - 1);
                const indexResult = "hello";
                let error = false;
                //-----
                if(!error){
                    resolve(indexResult);
                } else {
                    reject('Something went wrong!');
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

I´m calling this function here.

```
export default function SendId(){
    React.useEffect(() => {
        /*$("#noteDisplay").on("click", ".remove", async (e) => {
            console.log("ola");
        });*/
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        $("#noteDisplay").on("click", ".remove", async (e) => {
            const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
        
            let index_note = { // the object
                index: await index()
            }
        
            let data = JSON.stringify(index_note);
        
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', `http://localhost:${PORT}/api/1`, true);
            xhr.send(data);
            console.log("the data was sent")
        });
        
    });
    return(null);
}
```

And with or without async await it always retuns curly braces, when i log it.
I console.log it this way(but i don't think that's the problem).

```
app.post("/api/:1", (req, res) =>{
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Sorry for the repeating question, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is about JavaScript, not Java, a completely different programming language. I have changed your question's tags for you as there is no sense in attracting the wrong experts to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are not added 'Content-Type': 'application/json' to your request headers. Maybe this is an issue

`xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`